# TikZ, Beamer and matrix node iterative highlight ending in unwanted displacement

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-matrix

I have this code, and I want the blue-circled node to not expand the whole table when highlighted. With the additional minimum size option, the table stay unchanged, but the node moves, which is quite ugly :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \footnotesize
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=1\pgflinewidth, column sep=1\pgflinewidth,
               nodes={rectangle, draw=gray, minimum height=2em,
               anchor=center, align=center,
               inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}]{
    1 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
    \alt<2->{11 & 11 & 11 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 13 & 13 & 13 & 14 & |[draw, circle, blue, text width=1.5em]| 14}
    {11 & 11 & 11 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 13 & 13 & 13 & 14 & 14 }\\
    14 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 17 & 17 & 18 & 18 & 18 & 18 & 19 \\
    19 & 20 & 20 & 20 & 23 & 26 & 29 & 29 & 31 & 32 & 32 & 34\\
     } ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Moreover, if someone knows a more elegant way to blend Beamer and TikZ matrix for changing nodes aspect, he's welcome! Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I fixed your code up a little bit, to make it easier for people to help. In the future, if you can try and provide a complete and minimal document that reproduces your problem, including the `\documentclass{...}`, the minimal set of `\usepackage{...}` that are necessary, and the `\begin{document}...\end{document}` it would be very helpful. Thank you! For more information, please see here: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Notice also that using this approach, the code simplifies (I added a `minimum width` value just for the example, but you can remove it if you don't want to use it):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \footnotesize
  \matrix (m) [
    matrix of nodes, 
    row sep=1\pgflinewidth, 
    column sep=1\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={
      rectangle, 
      draw=gray, 
      minimum height=2em,
      anchor=center, 
      align=center,
      minimum width=2em,
      inner sep=0pt, 
      outer sep=0pt
      }
    ]
    {
    1 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
    11 & 11 & 11 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 13 & 13 & 13 & 14 & |[onslide=<2->{circle,overlay,blue}]|14 \\
    14 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 17 & 17 & 18 & 18 & 18 & 18 & 19 \\
    19 & 20 & 20 & 20 & 23 & 26 & 29 & 29 & 31 & 32 & 32 & 34\\
     };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An animation of the result:

[image]